# Wildcard for Chrome search?

Tags: google-chrome, search, wildcards

I want to search for a word on a page.  I know the first letter is a P the last letter is a L and there are 4 letters in-between them.

How can I search for this word?

Comment: I was talking about using CTRL+F...

Comment: Try this Chrome extension 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the linked duplicate has been deleted. To be clear: it was deleted after being considered off-topic, but the current question does not explicitly ask for software recommendations, so IMO it should stay. It shouldn't be marked as "duplicate" of a *deleted* question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome's "Find in page" search function does not support wildcards.

You can install the `highlight regexp` bookmarklet from [Squarefree](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagedata.html), which will allow you to search for JavaScript regexps: `P.{4}L` or `\bP.{4}L\b` (the latter also matches word boundaries).